# How to type \sim above another symbol x?

Tags: symbols

I want to put a "~" above x, just like `\hat x` but replacing `\hat` with `\sim`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you're after `\tilde x`.

Comment: Or `\widetilde` if the character is (or are) long.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, good remark!