# How to write a tilde over a sigma?

Tags: tilde

Good evening to everybody here.. My problem is how to write a "tilde" over a symbol (sigma for the precision) in the text mode..
Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to type `\sim` above another symbol x?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20382/5764) Use `$\tilde{\sigma}$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you type the sigma, to begin with? Is the “tilde” the Greek circumflex accent?

Comment: @Werner Note *text mode*

Comment: In my opinion, the use of "text mode" here is not used correctly. We'll wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @egreg, how to write a sigma in text mode? I can only imagine `$\sigma$`.

Comment: @Sigur I guess that Greeks often use their sigmas in text mode.

Comment: However, the circumflex accent doesn't go over a sigma.

Comment: @egreg: only ancient greek has a circumflex accent. Modern Greek only has an acute accent, so this is  not a problem for most today Greek people – apart from the fact that accents can happen only with vowels or diphtongs.

Answer (score 4):

If by "text mode" you mean you don't want the sigma to look like it's typeset in math mode you can try using the `upgreek` package. Compare below.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
$\tilde{\sigma}\tilde{\upsigma}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found the way to do that! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question, please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the tick/checkmark to the left of the answer. This shows other people that this is "the correct answer", in your opinion, and assigns points to the answerer and also to you. The question will then be handled as "done" which is important for the housekeeping of the site.